# Full-Calendar 5 drag moves all events

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to select one event at a time and drag it, but it always ends up moving all of the events in the same way.
FYI: `editable: true, selectable: true,`

What I am looking for is any ideas for what triggers "move all".

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue, because I can't immediately reproduce the problem using a basic demo - see https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNgarPP. Note that as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object, events with the same `groupId` will all be dragged together. It's unclear if that's the scenario you're in or not, because you provided us with no code or sample data. See also [ask].

Comment: It was the groupId that was causing the problem.  And it also helps me to see how I can organize moving, etc.  Thanks much for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADysons answer is right - watch that groupId.  It hooks the events together so that they get dragged as a group.